# Django rest framework and cross origin requests

Tags: django, rest, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I try to do some request from a javascript client to rest api build with Django rest framework.
All GET request to /api/test are public, then no session or token or watever are needed.
All POST to api/test are private and user have to use oauth2

According to [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/), I have to manage cross origin request with [django-core-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/). After installing this module to my django, I've set
`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True` but:
1) is it a good practice ?
2) is there a good solution to allow cross origin request only on some points ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With django-core-headers you can restrict CORS origins with `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` and `CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST`. If you don't *need* to allow arbitrary origins, then set those; otherwise, you're good.

You could, if you wanted to, write a decorator to check origin in your views to see if it matches a desired origin (perhaps something set on whatever model is tracking which users are authorized for POST requests?). But if you're allowing GET requests from any arbitrary origin, and don't care where POST requests come from as long as they are authorized, then you're in the clear--after all, how can you restrict origin if you don't know where clients might make requests from?

Comment: thanks for answer. Unfortunately, request can be done from customers browser then I cannot set a White list :(